# Regex Filename Not Matching

Tags: regex, perl

I'm running a Perl script that someone else wrote for me, and I've noticed that the following regex doesn't seem to match my files which are named "Film CD 1.avi", "Film2 CD 1.avi", etc.:

```
$name = (split (/[ ]*CD[ ]*1/i, $in_avi))[0];
```

Does anyone know what I need to do to correct it?

The full code is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

########################################################################
#                                                Configuration Details                                          #
########################################################################

# Array of movies to convert
my @MOVIES_TO_CONVERT; # = ('The Figher', 'The Fifth Element');

# Directory where the split AVI files are stored
my $MOVIE_IN_PATH = 'D:\split';

# Directory where the combined AVI files will be stored
my $MOVIE_OUT_PATH = 'D:\combined';

# Full path to the avidemux executable
my $AVIDEMUX = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux\avidemux.exe';

########################################################################
#                                                          Functions                                                      #
########################################################################

# Return an array of all the AVI files in the specified directory.
sub get_avis_in_directory
{
        my $dh; # Directory handle
        my $dir; # Current directory
        my @avis; # Array of file names to return

        opendir ($dh, $dir = shift) or die "Failed to open directory $dir: $!\n";
        while (readdir $dh)
        {
                next if (/^\.{1,2}/);
                $_ = $dir . "\\" . $_;
                push (@avis, $_) if (-f $_ and /.*\.avi$/i);
        }
        closedir $dh;

        return (@avis);
}

########################################################################
#                                                         Entry Point                                                    #
########################################################################

die "Input directory $MOVIE_IN_PATH does not exist!\n" unless (-d $MOVIE_IN_PATH);
die "Output directory $MOVIE_OUT_PATH does not exist!\n" unless (-d $MOVIE_OUT_PATH);

# This variable represents the actual names and paths of movies to be converted.
# It will either be built from the files specified in @MOVIES_TO_CONVERT manually, or
# built dynamically based on the files in the source and destination paths.
my @movies_formatted; # Array of hashes of movies to convert

if ($#MOVIES_TO_CONVERT == -1)
{
        my @in_avis; # Array of AVI files in the input directory
        my @out_avis; # Array of AVI files in the ouput directory

        @in_avis = get_avis_in_directory ($MOVIE_IN_PATH);
        @out_avis = get_avis_in_directory ($MOVIE_OUT_PATH);

        for my $in_avi (@in_avis)
        {
                if ($in_avi =~ /.*[ ]*CD[ ]*1\.avi$/i)
                {
                        my $rec; # Temporary hash variable
                        my $name; # Name of the move we are processing
                        $name = (split (/[ ]*CD[ ]*1/i, $in_avi))[0];
                        $name = (split (/$MOVIE_IN_PATH[\\\/]{1}/i, $name))[1];

                        for my $in_avi_2 (@in_avis)
                        {
                                if ($in_avi_2 =~ /^$MOVIE_IN_PATH\\$name[ ]*CD[ ]*2\.avi$/i)
                                {
                                        $rec->{'part2'} = $in_avi_2;
                                        last;
                                }
                        }

                        if (defined $rec->{'part2'})
                        {
                                for my $out_avi (@out_avis)
                                {
                                        if ($out_avi =~ /$name\.avi$/i)
                                        {
                                                $rec->{'output'} = $out_avi;
                                                last;
                                        }
                                }

                                unless (defined $rec->{'output'})
                                {
                                        $rec->{'part1'} = $in_avi;
                                        $rec->{'output'} = "$MOVIE_OUT_PATH\\$name.avi";
                                        push (@movies_formatted, $rec);
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}
else
{
        my $rec; # Temporary hash variable

        for my $name (@MOVIES_TO_CONVERT)
        {
                $rec = {};
                $rec->{'part1'} = "$MOVIE_IN_PATH\\$name CD 1.avi";
                $rec->{'part2'} = "$MOVIE_IN_PATH\\$name CD 2.avi";
                $rec->{'output'} = "$MOVIE_OUT_PATH\\$name.avi";
                push (@movies_formatted, $rec);
        }
}

for my $movie (@movies_formatted)
{
        my $convert_cmd = "\"$AVIDEMUX\" --load \"" . $movie->{'part1'} . "\" --append \"" . $movie->{'part2'} . "\" --force-smart --save \"" . $movie->{'output'} . "\" --quit";
        print "$convert_cmd\n";
        die "Unable to convert $movie->{'output'}!\n" if (system "$convert_cmd");
}
```

The script is from http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1128384-batch-file-to-run-command-on-joining-video-files by xorangekiller.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Please improve your question by posting some [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) code you've applied to the problem, all **relevant** error messages exactly as they appear, and whatever samples you're testing against.

Comment: @Lindrian - I have added the full code.  Basically the script does nothing at all.  All the parameters at the top are correct as it works when I specify the file names, but I want it to go through the directory itself like it is designed to do so.

Comment: @CodeGnome - It shows this error after I added "use warnings;": Use of uninitialized value $name in regexp compilation at films.pl line 76.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslash in `$MOVIE_IN_PATH` is being removed by interpolating it into the regular expression. Change *both* the `split` commands to

```
$name = (split(/\Q$MOVIE_IN_PATH\E[\\\/]{1}/i, $name))[1];
```

i.e. add the `\Q` ... `\E` to escape any regex metacharacters.

Your friend doesn't appear to be a particularly good Perl programmer. You may want to try this code instead.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Basename;
use File::Spec;

# Configuration Details
#######################

# Array of movies to convert
my @MOVIES_TO_CONVERT;    # = ('The Fighter', 'The Fifth Element');

# Directory where the split AVI files are stored
my $MOVIE_IN_PATH = 'D:\split';

# Directory where the combined AVI files will be stored
my $MOVIE_OUT_PATH = 'D:\combined';

# Full path to the avidemux executable
my $AVIDEMUX = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux\avidemux.exe';

sub get_avis_in_directory {
  opendir my $dh, $MOVIE_IN_PATH or die $!;
  return grep {
    /\.avi$/ and -f File::Spec->catfile($MOVIE_IN_PATH, $_)
  } readdir $dh;
}

-d $MOVIE_IN_PATH or die qq(Input directory "$MOVIE_IN_PATH" does not exist!\n);
-d $MOVIE_OUT_PATH or die qq(Output directory "$MOVIE_OUT_PATH" does not exist!\n);

my @movies_formatted;    # Array of hashes of movies to convert

if (@MOVIES_TO_CONVERT) {

  for my $name (@MOVIES_TO_CONVERT) {
    my $rec = {};
    $rec->{part1}  = File::Spec->catfile($MOVIE_IN_PATH, "$name CD 1.avi");
    $rec->{part2}  = File::Spec->catfile($MOVIE_IN_PATH, "$name CD 2.avi");
    $rec->{output} = File::Spec->catfile($MOVIE_OUT_PATH, "$name.avi");
    push @movies_formatted, $rec;
  }
}
else {

  my @in_avis  = get_avis_in_directory($MOVIE_IN_PATH);

  for my $in_avi (@in_avis) {

    next unless $in_avi =~ /^(.+?)\s*CD\s*1\.avi$/i;

    my $name = $1;

    my $rec = {};
    $rec->{part1} = $in_avi;
    ($rec->{part2}) = grep /^\Q$name\E\s*CD\s*2\.avi$/i, @in_avis;

    if ($rec->{part2}) {
      $rec->{$_} = File::Spec->catfile($MOVIE_IN_PATH, $rec->{$_}) for qw/ part1 part2 /;
      $rec->{output} = File::Spec->catfile($MOVIE_OUT_PATH, "$name.avi");
      push @movies_formatted, $rec;
    }

  }
}

for my $movie (@movies_formatted) {

  my $convert_cmd = sprintf '"%s" --load "%s" --append "%s" --force-smart --save "%s" --quit',
      $AVIDEMUX, @{$movie}{qw/ part1 part2 output /};
  print "$convert_cmd\n";

  die "Unable to convert $movie->{'output'}!\n" if (system $convert_cmd);
}
```

Comment: like this: $name = (split(/\Q$MOVIE_IN_PATH\E[\\\/]{1}/i, $name))[1];

if ($in_avi_2 =~ /^\Q$MOVIE_IN_PATH\E\\$name[ ]*CD[ ]*2\.avi$/i)

Comment: The script runs now but Avidemux closes upon startup every time and this is what is shown in the console:

Comment: C:\>perl films.pl
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux\avidemux.exe" --load "D:\split\Bourne Identity
CD 1.avi" --append "D:\split\Bourne Identity CD 2.avi" --force-smart --save "D:\
combined\Bourne Identity.avi" --quit
Can't spawn ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux\avidemux.exe" --load "D:\split\Bou
rne Identity CD 1.avi" --append "D:\split\Bourne Identity CD 2.avi" --force-smar
t --save "D:\combined\Bourne Identity.avi" --quit": No error at films.pl line 12
4.
Unable to convert D:\combined\Bourne Identity.avi!

C:\>

Comment: The weird spaces are due to copying from the command window.  I have checked all the file paths and they are valid.  The video does append from the GUI and also if I enter everything in the command window manually (without the script).

Comment: Change `system "$convert_cmd"` to `system $convert_cmd`

Comment: Makes no difference and Avidemux still crashes on load. Whilst I've been waiting for your reply I've been trying to figure out what is wrong and I entered just this in the command line and that also failed: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux\avidemux.exe" --load "D:\split\Bourne Identity CD 1.avi" --quit

Comment: What error do you get? It sounds like the path to AVIdemux is wrong. Mine is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5`

Comment: The same error as before.  The path is right because I can open it if I put it in Run.  I also tried the line on its own from the avidemux folder and I get the same error.  I think the error is due to the way the command is formatted so something isn't right somewhere in the code.  I am just going to specify the file names, as I know that that works.

Comment: You didn't say what the error was before. Does the AVIdemux app start with an error window? What does it say? You said the command-line failes with just a load and a quit, so it doesn't look like the command is wrong. Can you get it to work from the command line? What does that look like?

Comment: Woah. That seems pretty severe. Does just `system $AVIDEMUX` from Perl work OK?

Comment: Sorry, how do I check that?

Comment: Argh! After all that it looks like my installation of Avidemux was ****ed.  I reinstalled it and it runs fine now with the changes you suggested.

Comment: Hehe glad to hear you've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

In what way doesn't it work?

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<DATA>) {
    my $in_avi = $_;
    my $name = (split (/[ ]*CD[ ]*1/i, $in_avi))[0];
    print "$name\n";
}

__DATA__
Film CD 1.avi
Film2 CD 1.avi
```

Prints:

```
Film
Film2
```

Comment: I added the full code to the original question.  It basically does nothing at the moment unless I specify the file names.

Comment: I ran the script with the "use warnings;" and it showed up hundreds of these errors: Use of uninitialized value $name in regexp compilation at films.pl line 76.